# Find first value in hash array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have the following array.

```
[
  {"title"=>"un", "link"=>nil, "description"=>""},
  {"title"=>"deux", "link"=>"https://apple.com", "description"=>"Products"},
  {"title"=>"three", "link"=>"http://www.amazon.com", "description"=>"Welcome"},
  {"title"=>"four", "link"=>"https://apple.com", "description"=>"iPad"},
]
```

I'd like to remove hashes whose link is `nil` or empty, an return an array of links to get:

```
["https://apple.com", "http://amazon"]
```

Not sure how to remove hashes and get unique links only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
a = [
{"title"=>"un", "link"=>nil, "description"=>""},
{"title"=>"deux", "link"=>"https://apple.com", "description"=>"Products"},
{"title"=>"three", "link"=>"http://www.amazon.com", "description"=>"Welcome"},
{"title"=>"four", "link"=>"https://apple.com", "description"=>"iPad"},
]
a.map{|data| data["link"] }.reject(&:blank?).uniq
```

**Explanation**:

a is the array of hashes

Map will go through each hash in the array and create a new array with just the "link" value. If the original hash didn't have a link key it will create a nil value in the new array.

```
Example result after map: 
[nil, "https://apple.com", "https://www.amazon.com", "https://apple.com"]
```

Reject then calls the rails active support method blank? on each item in the array and if blank? returns true returns a new array without the value:

```
[nil.blank?, "https://apple.com".blank?, "https://www.amazon.com".blank?, "https://apple.com".blank?]
Result:    
["https://apple.com", "https://www.amazon.com", "https://apple.com"]
```

Uniq then generates an array without duplicates (an alternative is to use a ruby set)

```
["https://apple.com", "https://www.amazon.com"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete explanation. I appreciate.

Answer (score 4):

To remove both empty (`""`) and `nil` values:

```
arr.map { |a| a["link"] }.reject(&:blank?).uniq
```

As @Arup pointed out `blank` is in Rails, pure Ruby solution would be:

```
arr.map { |a| a["link"] }.reject{|e| e == "" || e == nil}.uniq
```

Comment: `#blank` is in rails.. not Ruby.. :D

Answer (score 2):

Please try like below code

```
arr.map {|o| o['link'] }.reject { |e| e.to_s.empty? }.uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do by:

```
 arr.map {|o| o['link'] }.compact.uniq
```

`compact` remove all `nil`s, and `uniq` returns the unique values.

Comment: It doesn't remove empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object) :

```
array.each_with_object([]) do |h, a|
  a << h['link'] unless h['link'].nil? || h['link'].empty?
end.uniq
# => ["https://apple.com", "http://www.amazon.com"]
```